# Loop through set of forms and display the appropriate when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My comment section has a "Reply" button. I want to show the appropriate form if the replied button is clicked. (The comments is up to 5)

I've tried the below code and it's not working for me

```
var comment = document.getElementsByClassName('showreply');

function replyComment() {
     var i;
     for(i = 0; i <= comment.lenght; i++) {
           comment[i].style.display='block';
     }
}
```

When I click on the Reply button, nothing happens...

Let me further break the question.

I have a web page that shows a file (stored in the database) when someone visits it (logged in user or guest).

When the file is shown, next is the comments (also stored in the database) for the file. Each comment has a button that says "Reply" and a reply form inside a div. The div is hidden by default.

Note that the comment is more than 1. So, I want to show appropriate reply form when the reply button is clicked...

Anyone know better way of achieving this.

I hope the code below will help you understand what I'm looking for...

```
<div class="music_comments">
                      <div class="comment_title"><i class="far fa-comments"></i> Comments (<?php echo $mcCount; ?>)</div>

                      <!-- Music Comments -->
                      <?php
                      while ($mccinfo = mysqli_fetch_array($mComments)) {
                          $ppid = $mccinfo['ID'];
                          $p = $mccinfo['poster'];

                          if($p != 'Guest') {
                              $poster = getUserInfo2($mccinfo['poster'], 'firstname'). ' ' . getUserInfo2($mccinfo['poster'], 'lastname');
                              $photo = getUserInfo2 ($p, 'photo');
                              $r = "<a href='/$p' title='$poster'>$poster</a>";
                          } else {
                              $poster = 'Guest';
                              $photo = '/images/avatar/avatar5.png';
                              $r = $poster;
                          }


                          $comment = $mccinfo['comment'];
                          $date = $mccinfo['date'];
                          $cq = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM banabase_musiccommentreply WHERE commentID=$ppid AND musicID=$id");

                          $clikecount = mysqli_num_rows( mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM banabase_musicreaction WHERE type=1 AND commentID=$ppid AND musicID=$id"));

                          $cdislikecount = mysqli_num_rows( mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM banabase_musicreaction WHERE type=2 AND commentID=$ppid AND musicID=$id"));

                        $k = (str_shuffle('ABCDEFGHabcdefgh1234567890'));
                        $resetCode = substr ($k, 0, round(strlen($k)/2, 1));

                        $k2 = md5 (rand(000000, 999999));
                        $k3 = md5 (rand(000000, 999999));
                        $resetCode2 = substr ($k2, 0, round(strlen($k2)/5, 1));
                        $resetCode3 = substr ($k3, 0, round(strlen($k3)/5, 1));

                        $r2 = $resetCode2;
                        $r3 = $resetCode3;

                        $r1 = $r2. $ppid . $resetCode;
                        $r3 = $r3. $id . $resetCode;


                          echo "<div class='comment'>
                          <table cellspacing='5' cellpadding='2'>
                            <tr>
                                <td width='6%'>
                                    <img src='$photo' height='50' width='50' alt='+' title='$poster'> 
                                </td>
                                <td width='94%'>
                                    <p style='margin-top: -2px; margin-bottom: 7px;'>
                                    <small>
                                   $r said:
                                    </small>
                                    <span class='msgtime right'>".timeAgo($date)."<span>
                                    </p>
                                    $comment<br>"; ?>
                                    <small class='comment-action right'>
                                    <a href='/music/react.php?like&cid=<?php echo $r1.'&mid='.$r3; ?>' title='Like'><i class='far fa-thumbs-up'></i></a> <?php echo $clikecount; ?> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href='/music/react.php?dislike&cid=<?php echo $r1.'&mid='.$r3; ?>' title='Dislike'><i class='far fa-thumbs-down'></i></a> <?php echo $cdislikecount; ?> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href='#reply' onclick="showForm();" title='Reply this comment'>Reply</a>
                                    </small>


                                <?php echo "</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>"; ?>


                      <!-- 1st Comment Reply Form -->
                        <div id='comment-reply' class="showreply">
                    <div id="reply" style="position: relative; top: -110px;"></div>
                  <center>
                      <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars('#'); ?>" method="post">
                          <h4 style="margin-bottom: 3px; color: #aaa;">Reply this Comment</h4>
                          <input type="hidden" name="poster" value="<?php if(isLoggedIn()) echo $user; else echo 'Guest'; ?>">
                          <input type="hidden" name="musicID" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                          <input type="hidden" name="commentID" value="<?php echo $ppid; ?>">
                          <textarea name='comment' width='40' rows='3'></textarea><br>
                          <input type="submit" name="reply" class="btn success" value="Reply">
                      </form>
                  </center>
                        </div>

                      <!-- First Comment Reply-->
                      <?php
                          while ($cr = mysqli_fetch_array($cq)) {

                          $r = $cr['ID'];
                          $rp = $cr['poster'];
                        $rrrcq = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM banabase_musiccommentreply WHERE commentID=$r AND musicID=$id");

                        if($rp != 'Guest') {
                            $prp = getUserInfo2($cr['poster'], 'firstname'). ' ' . getUserInfo2($cr['poster'], 'lastname');
                            $rphoto = getUserInfo2 ($rp, 'photo');
                            $rpl = "<a href='/$rp' title='$prp'>$prp</a>";
                        } else {
                            $prp = 'Guest';
                            $rphoto = '/images/avatar/avatar5.png';
                            $rpl = $prp;
                          }

                          $rc = $cr['comment'];
                          $rd = $cr['date'];

                        $rlikecount = mysqli_num_rows( mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM banabase_musicreaction WHERE type=1 AND commentID=$r AND musicID=$id"));

                        $rdislikecount = mysqli_num_rows( mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM banabase_musicreaction WHERE type=2 AND commentID=$r AND musicID=$id"));

                        $k = (str_shuffle('ABCDEFGHabcdefgh1234567890'));
                        $resetCode = substr ($k, 0, round(strlen($k)/2, 1));

                        $k2 = md5 (rand(000000, 999999));
                        $k3 = md5 (rand(000000, 999999));
                        $resetCode2 = substr ($k2, 0, round(strlen($k2)/5, 1));
                        $resetCode3 = substr ($k3, 0, round(strlen($k3)/5, 1));

                        $r2 = $resetCode2;
                        $r3 = $resetCode3;

                        $r1 = $r2. $r . $resetCode;
                        $r3 = $r3. $id . $resetCode;

                              echo "<div class='comment' style='margin-left: 40px; background: #eee;'>
                          <table cellspacing='5' cellpadding='2'>
                            <tr>
                                <td width='6%'>
                                    <img src='$rphoto' height='50' width='50' alt='+' title='$prp'> 
                                </td>
                                <td width='94%'>
                                    <p style='margin-top: -2px; margin-bottom: 7px;'>
                                    <small>
                                    $rpl replied:
                                    </small> 
                                    <span class='msgtime right'>".timeAgo($rd)."<span>
                                    </p>
                                    $rc<br>"; ?>

                                    <small class='comment-action right'>
                                    <a href='/music/react.php?like&cid=<?php echo $r1.'&mid='.$r3; ?>' title='Like'><i class='far fa-thumbs-up'></i></a> <?php echo $rlikecount; ?> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href='/music/react.php?dislike&cid=<?php echo $r1.'&mid='.$r3; ?>' title='Dislike'><i class='far fa-thumbs-down'></i></a> <?php echo $rdislikecount; ?> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href='#reply' onclick="showForm();" title='Reply this comment'>Reply</a>
                                    </small>

                      <!-- Second Comment Reply Form-->
                      <div id='comment-reply' class="showreply">
                    <div id="reply" style="position: relative; top: -110px;"></div>
                  <center>
                      <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars('#'); ?>" method="post">
                          <h4 style="margin-bottom: 3px; color: #aaa;">Reply this Comment</h4>
                          <input type="hidden" name="poster" value="<?php if(isLoggedIn()) echo $user; else echo 'Guest'; ?>">
                          <input type="hidden" name="musicID" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                          <input type="hidden" name="commentID" value="<?php echo $r; ?>">
                          <textarea name='comment' width='40' rows='3'></textarea><br>
                          <input type="submit" name="reply" class="btn success" value="Reply">
                      </form>
                  </center>
                        </div>

                      <!-- Second Comment Reply-->

                      <?php echo "
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>";


                        while ($rrrcr = mysqli_fetch_array($rrrcq)) {
                          $rrrr = $rrrcr['ID'];
                          $rrrrp = $rrrcr['poster'];
                            $rrcq = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM banabase_musiccommentreply WHERE commentID=$rrrr AND musicID=$id");

                        if($rrrrp != 'Guest') {
                            $rrrprp = getUserInfo2($rrrcr['poster'], 'firstname'). ' ' . getUserInfo2($rrrcr['poster'], 'lastname');
                            $rrrrphoto = getUserInfo2 ($rrrrp, 'photo');
                            $rrrrpl = "<a href='/$rp' title='$rrrprp'>$rrrprp</a>";
                        } else {
                            $rrrprp = 'Guest';
                            $rrrrphoto = '/images/avatar/avatar5.png';
                            $rrrrpl = $rrrprp;
                          }

                          $rrrrc = $rrrcr['comment'];
                          $rrrrd = $rrrcr['date'];

                        $r2likecount = mysqli_num_rows( mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM banabase_musicreaction WHERE type=1 AND commentID=$rrrr AND musicID=$id"));

                        $r2dislikecount = mysqli_num_rows( mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM banabase_musicreaction WHERE type=2 AND commentID=$r AND musicID=$id"));

                        $k = (str_shuffle('ABCDEFGHabcdefgh1234567890'));
                        $resetCode = substr ($k, 0, round(strlen($k)/2, 1));

                        $k2 = md5 (rand(000000, 999999));
                        $k3 = md5 (rand(000000, 999999));
                        $resetCode2 = substr ($k2, 0, round(strlen($k2)/5, 1));
                        $resetCode3 = substr ($k3, 0, round(strlen($k3)/5, 1));

                        $r2 = $resetCode2;
                        $r3 = $resetCode3;

                        $r1 = $r2. $rrrr . $resetCode;
                        $r3 = $r3. $id . $resetCode;


                              echo "<div class='comment' style='margin-left: 40px;'>
                          <table cellspacing='5' cellpadding='2'>
                            <tr>
                                <td width='6%'>
                                    <img src='$rrrrphoto' height='50' width='50' alt='+' title='$rrrprp'> 
                                </td>
                                <td width='94%'>
                                    <p style='margin-top: -2px; margin-bottom: 7px;'>
                                    <small>
                                    $rrrrpl replied:
                                    </small> 
                                    <span class='msgtime right'>".timeAgo($rrrrd)."<span>
                                    </p>
                                    $rrrrc<br>"; ?>

                                    <small class='comment-action right'>
                                    <a href='/music/react.php?like&cid=<?php echo $r1.'&mid='.$r3; ?>' title='Like'><i class='far fa-thumbs-up'></i></a> <?php echo $r2likecount; ?> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href='/music/react.php?dislike&cid=<?php echo $r1.'&mid='.$r3; ?>' title='Dislike'><i class='far fa-thumbs-down'></i></a> <?php echo $r2dislikecount; ?> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href='#reply' onclick="showForm();" title='Reply this comment'>Reply</a>
                                    </small>

                      <!-- Other Comment Reply Form-->

                      <div id='comment-reply' class="showreply">
                    <div id="reply" style="position: relative; top: -110px;"></div>
                  <center>
                      <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars('#'); ?>" method="post">
                          <h4 style="margin-bottom: 3px; color: #aaa;">Reply this Comment</h4>
                          <input type="hidden" name="poster" value="<?php if(isLoggedIn()) echo $user; else echo 'Guest'; ?>">
                          <input type="hidden" name="musicID" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                          <input type="hidden" name="commentID" value="<?php echo $rrrr; ?>">
                          <textarea name='comment' width='40' rows='3'></textarea><br>
                          <input type="submit" name="reply" class="btn success" value="Reply">
                      </form>
                  </center>
                        </div>

                      <?php echo "
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>";

                        while ($rrcr = mysqli_fetch_array($rrcq)) {
                          $rrr = $rrcr['ID'];
                          $rrrp = $rrcr['poster'];

                        if($rrrp != 'Guest') {
                            $rrprp = getUserInfo2($rrcr['poster'], 'firstname'). ' ' . getUserInfo2($rrcr['poster'], 'lastname');
                            $prrphoto = getUserInfo2 ($rrrp, 'photo');
                            $rrrpl = "<a href='/$rrrp' title='$rrprp'>$rrprp</a>";
                        } else {
                            $rrprp = 'Guest';
                            $prrphoto = '/images/avatar/avatar5.png';
                            $rrrpl = $rrprp;
                          }
                          $prrc = $rrcr['comment'];
                          $rrrd = $rrcr['date'];


                        $r3likecount = mysqli_num_rows( mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM banabase_musicreaction WHERE type=1 AND commentID=$rrr AND musicID=$id"));

                        $r3dislikecount = mysqli_num_rows( mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM banabase_musicreaction WHERE type=2 AND commentID=$rrr AND musicID=$id"));

                        $k = (str_shuffle('ABCDEFGHabcdefgh1234567890'));
                        $resetCode = substr ($k, 0, round(strlen($k)/2, 1));

                        $k2 = md5 (rand(000000, 999999));
                        $k3 = md5 (rand(000000, 999999));
                        $resetCode2 = substr ($k2, 0, round(strlen($k2)/5, 1));
                        $resetCode3 = substr ($k3, 0, round(strlen($k3)/5, 1));

                        $r2 = $resetCode2;
                        $r3 = $resetCode3;

                        $r1 = $r2. $rrr . $resetCode;
                        $r3 = $r3. $id . $resetCode;


                              echo "<div class='comment' style='margin-left: 40px; background: #eeee;'>
                          <table cellspacing='5' cellpadding='2'>
                            <tr>
                                <td width='6%'>
                                    <img src='$prrphoto' height='50' width='50' alt='+' title='$rrprp'> 
                                </td>
                                <td width='94%'>
                                    <p style='margin-top: -2px; margin-bottom: 7px;'>
                                    <small>
                                    $rrrpl replied:
                                    </small> 
                                    <span class='msgtime right'>".timeAgo($rrrd)."<span>
                                    </p>
                                    $prrc<br>"; ?>

                                    <small class='comment-action right'>
                                    <a href='/music/react.php?like&cid=<?php echo $r1.'&mid='.$r3; ?>' title='Like'><i class='far fa-thumbs-up'></i></a> <?php echo $r3likecount; ?> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href='/music/react.php?dislike&cid=<?php echo $r1.'&mid='.$r3; ?>' title='Dislike'><i class='far fa-thumbs-down'></i></a> <?php echo $r3dislikecount; ?>
                                    </small>

                      <?php 
                echo "
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        </div>";
                        }
                echo "
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        </div>";
                        }

                echo "
                        </div>";
                        }

                echo "
                        </div>";
                        }

                          ?>
                  </div>
                  <div id="addcomment" style="position: relative; top: -70px;"></div>
                  <center>
                      <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars('#'); ?>" method="post">
                          <h4 style="margin-bottom: 3px; color: #aaa;">Add a Comment</h4>
                          <input type="hidden" name="poster" value="<?php if(isLoggedIn()) echo $user; else echo 'Guest'; ?>">
                          <input type="hidden" name="musicID" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                          <textarea name='comment' width='40' rows='3'></textarea><br>
                          <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn success" value="Comment">
                      </form>
                  </center>
```

Comment: Change `<=` to `<`. The array index starts from 0, so you will get array index out of bound for last iteration.

Comment: Where are you adding `click` event listener?

Comment: Please describe HTML along with `click` event of your JS code.

Comment: It doesn't work too

Comment: this is the html tag ```<a href='#reply' onclick="replyComment();" title='Reply this comment'>Reply</a>```

Answer (score 1):

You've misspelled the word 'length' in `comment.length`, as side note you may want to change that variable name to 'comments' since it contains more than one comment.

Also as was mentioned above you don't need `<=`, `<` should be sufficient.

Comment: I've corrected it, nothing happens when the button is clicked

Comment: You have to attach an event handler to call your function, as described above. Like so: `$('.showreply').click(function(){
$('#reply').show();
$(this).closest('.comment').append($('#reply'));
})`

Comment: If that doesn't make sense. I would recommend taking a short jQuery course (https://css-tricks.com/lodge/learn-jquery/). That is fairly rudimentary jQuery, so I think some fundamentals would help you here.

Answer (score 1):

If you use jquery, you can use closest method to get relative comment.

```
$('.showreply').click(function(){
   $(this).closest('.comment').css('border', '1px solid red');
})
```

```js
$('.showreply').click(function(){
$('#reply').show();
$(this).closest('.comment').append($('#reply'));
})
```

```css
#reply{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='allcomment'>
<div class='comment'>
<textarea>Test</textarea>
<button class='showreply'>Reply</button>
</div>

<div class='comment'>
<textarea>Test</textarea>
<button class='showreply'>Reply</button>
</div>

<div class='comment'>
<textarea>Test</textarea>
<button class='showreply'>Reply</button>
</div>

<form id='reply'>
Reply here
<textarea></textarea>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to show a red border color. I want to display a reply form when the button is clicked

Comment: This is not working for me too. I'll update the question and post the full code, so that you'll see what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: I've edited the question. Please read again and adjust your code if necessary

Comment: Look at the question again. I've updated it and showed my code. Check through to see if you understand what I want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

We can use siblings inbuilt method in jQuery. Here is working demo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demonstrating Jquery siblings()</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.form').hide(); //Initially hide all comment form

            $('.showreply').click(function(){
                $(this).siblings('.form').slideDown();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
    .cmnt {
        margin:10px 0 10px 0;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class='allcomment'>

    <div class='comment'>
        <br/><br/>
        <textarea>File 1</textarea><br />
        <div class="cmnt">
            Coment testing sample text...
            <button class='showreply'>Reply</button><br />
            <div class="form">
                <input type="text"  placeholder="Field 1" />
                <input type="text"  placeholder="Field 2" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cmnt">
            Coment testing sample text...
            <button class='showreply'>Reply</button><br />
            <div class="form">
                <input type="text"  placeholder="Field 1" />
                <input type="text"  placeholder="Field 2" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='comment'>
        <br/><br/>
        <textarea>File 2</textarea><br />
        <div class="cmnt">
            Coment testing sample text...
            <button class='showreply'>Reply</button><br />
            <div class="form">
                <input type="text"  placeholder="Field 1" />
                <input type="text"  placeholder="Field 2" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cmnt">
            Coment testing sample text...
            <button class='showreply'>Reply</button><br />
            <div class="form">
                <input type="text"  placeholder="Field 1" />
                <input type="text"  placeholder="Field 2" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cmnt">
            Coment testing sample text...
            <button class='showreply'>Reply</button><br />
            <div class="form">
                <input type="text"  placeholder="Field 1" />
                <input type="text"  placeholder="Field 2" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this too doesn't work... I want to post the whole code, but the site wont allow me to. They said my post has more codes

Comment: I've edited the question. Please read again and adjust your code if necessary

Comment: May be this helps.?

Comment: ```$('.form').hide();``` This only hides the first form. Others are shown

Comment: Nope it will hide all the forms with class `form`.

Comment: It is only hiding the first form.

Comment: Run again in ur browser. I have tested twice here. It should hide.

Comment: I'm on mobile now. I'll show my code snippet when I switch to PC 

Comment: Look at the question again. I've updated it and showed my code. Check through to see if you understand what I want to achieve